# Using Devanagri package in latex

Tags: indic, hindi

I want to write in hindi in latex

मेरे माता और पिता को समर्पित|

I am using devanagri package and I want to put this in the document using the command {\dn .............}. If somebody can translate the above lines in Devanagari then i can put these in in the blank and get it to work. Also, if there i a tool readily available like google translate, it will be helpful if someone can point out

Comment: My new year resolution is to improve my TeX skills

Comment: I know nothing about Devanagri. But have you tried either pdflatex and `babel` or xelatex with `fontspec` (with Devanagri-capable font) and `polyglossia`? In both cases you would probably be able to write directly in Devanagri in unicode using `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207310/devanagari-characters-and-pdflalitex by the way.

Comment: I tried using XeLatex or other compilers, it seems my project doesn't work at all, prints some gibberish. This is the only package that works.

Comment: related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199773/how-to-type-hindi-words-in-latex

Answer (score 11):

Short answer: For the text in the question, you can use:

```
{\dn m\?r\? mAtA aOr EptA ko smEp\0t.}
```

Longer answer follows.

---

## Recommended way (XeTeX and Unicode font)

In general, to type Devanagari in (La)TeX, it is best to use a Unicode-aware engine like XeTeX [or LuaTeX, but LuaTeX's support for Indic (and most non-Latin) scripts is rather poor]. For example, you can just compile the following with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hindifont{Noto Sans Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari] % Use any Devanagari font on your system

\begin{document}
This is Latin script and {\hindifont यह है देवनागरी}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output with XeTeX]

or for better results if you have a lot of Hindi text, it is recommended to use the `polyglossia` package too (for things like hyphenation and other language-specific rules):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia} % Automatically loads fontspec
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{hindi}
\newfontfamily\hindifont{Noto Sans Devanagari}[Script=Devanagari] % Use any Devanagari font on your system

\begin{document}
This is Latin script and \texthindi{यह है देवनागरी}.
\end{document}
```

---

## Deprecated but still working way (non-Unicode font)

If for some reason you cannot use XeTeX, then you can use the old `devanagari` package. This requires two passes. First, you type everything into a `.dn` (not `.tex`) file, with the Devanagari parts inside `{\dn ...}`, using Velthuis encoding for the Devanagari text. (Invoke `texdoc velthuis` to read [the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/velthuis/manual.pdf) for details.) Then you run `devnag` on this `.dn` file, to create a `.tex` file. Then you compile this `.tex` file.

For example, for the text in the question, you can create a `.dn` file with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{devanagari}

\begin{document}
This is English. {\dn mere maataa aura pitaa ko samarpita|} English again.
\end{document}
```

Then running `devnag` file on this `.dn` file produces the following `.tex` file:

```
\def\DevnagVersion{2.17}\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{devanagari}

\begin{document}
This is English. {\dn m\?r\? mAtA aOr EptA ko smEp\0t.} English again.
\end{document}
```

Now you can compile this file with say `pdflatex`, to get:

[image: dn/pdflatex]

### Tools

- To go from the Devanagari to the required Velthuis transliteration (e.g. from `मेरे माता और पिता को समर्पित` to `{\dn mere maataa aura pitaa ko samarpita}`, you can use [this tool I wrote a long time ago](http://shreevatsa.appspot.com/sanskrit/transliterate.html) (or just learn the conventions from the documentation and type it manually).
- To go from the `.dn` file to the `.tex` file, you need the `devnag` processor installed, which comes with TeX Live. If you're using a different distribution, it may be under a different name, or you may have to [compile it yourself](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33360/how-can-i-compile-the-devanagari-preprocessor-in-linux).
- To go directly from Devanagari to the `\dn` convention and skip the previous two steps (e.g. from `मेरे माता और पिता को समर्पित` to `{\dn m\?r\? mAtA aOr EptA ko smEp\0t.}`, you may be able to use [the Python script](https://gist.github.com/shreevatsa/4d476ac26a367fa68984d8c06867d7dd#file-get-dn-py) I wrote for [another answer a few months ago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296266/old-sanskrit-fonts-and-unicode-input/358887#358887).

Comment: I know that this is an old question/answer, but this was really helpful for me as i also wanted something similar in my thesis. However, I am unable to figure out how to write "मेरी प्यारी दादी की याद में, और मेरे माता, पिता एवं दादाजी को समर्पित |". The {\dn m\?r\? mAtA aOr EptA ko smEp\0t.} bits work perfectly, but I would really appreciate if you could guide me on writing the above. Many thanks for your help, I am quite a novice with this package! @ShreevatsaR

Comment: @JChat You're welcome. Sure I can help, but first could you tell me what part of this answer was unclear? Apart from the `xelatex`/`lualatex` method (are you sure you can't use those instead of `pdflatex`?), the answer linked to two tools (one for going from Devanagari to Velthuis and then running`devnag`, and the other a Python script to bypass `devnag` directly)—which of the two tools did you try, and what happened?

Comment: @JChat (BTW the answer to your question is that for `मेरी प्यारी दादी की याद में, और मेरे माता, पिता एवं दादाजी को समर्पित |` you can write `{\dn m\?rF =yArF dAdF kF yAd m\?{\qva}{\rs ,\re} aOr m\?r\? mAtA{\rs ,\re} EptA ev\2 dAdAjF ko smEp\0t .}` —try it and let me know—but I'd still like to know how I could make the answer clearer so that the reader has the ability to figure this out by themselves.)

Comment: thanks - I am using Overleaf to write my thesis, so am having problems in utilising system-installed fonts (and it throws errors when writing directly in Hindi). Thereby, your short answer that uses non-unicode font worked like a charm for me. I appreciate the Python script - though is there any resource or web service/application for this which can directly translate from Hindi to the required format without executing the script locally (as it would be very helpful for users who use Overleaf)? Anyways, your answer worked perfectly for me, many thanks and cheers!

Comment: @JChat A web application is a good idea, thanks… I'll think about it.

Comment: Actually a web application isn't so trivial because the Python script just calls either `devnag` or `skt`, i.e. that binary needs to run on the backend. May look into it nevertheless.

Comment: The web application (for devnagri ---> Velthuis) you mentioned in your answer, leaves the nuqta out. For eg: [उन्हे नुक्कड़ नाटक के] --> unhe nukka.da़ naa.taka ke. Notice the nuqta at index 13.

Comment: @Ritwik Right, it was written for Sanskrit so I didn't pay much heed to the nuqta (looks like the manual uses "Ra" for "ड़", haven't tried it).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I took some liberty to modify your gist, now it handles the nuqta https://gist.github.com/ritwikmishra/9f8d6de45aff8fbe959d4260269d9eeb

Comment: @Ritwik Great, thanks.