# New command without arguments in LaTeX

Tags: macros, pdftex

I'm using the `devanagari` package to typeset Hindi/Sanskrit alphabet in LaTeX.
I have defined commands like `\newcommand{\S}{{\dn saa}}`, `\newcommand{\R}{{\dn re}}` etc.
From a usage point of view, I would like to use these commands in the following way:

1. `\S\R` should be formatted without space between the two characters: [image: output without space]
2. `\S \R` should be formatted with space between the two characters: [image: output with space]

First one works just fine, but the second one doesn't. 
I know writing it as `\S{} \R{}` would do the job, but I'm trying to avoid writing the two extra braces.
Similarly, writing it as `\S\ \R\` is what I'm currently doing right now, but it would be ideal if there is a way to get read of the trailing backslashes.
Furthermore, I have looked at using the `xspace` package, but it doesn't seem to work with the `devanagari` package.

A very basic working example is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{devanagari}

\newcommand{\S}{{\dn saa}}
\newcommand{\R}{{\dn re}}

\begin{document}
\S\R \\     % output expected as #1
\S \R \\    % output expected as #2
\end{document}
```

To run the above snippet:

1. Save the file as `sample.dn`
2. Run `devnag sample.dn` in the terminal, this generates a file `sample.tex`
3. Run `pdflatex sample.tex` in the terminal to generate the PDF

Is there any way to format `\S \R` as shown in #2 above?

Comment: Just curious: why are you using the old `devanagari` package instead of using XeTeX / LuaTeX which give you access to any Devanagari font you like, and your input can be more straightforward too (just UTF-8 Devanagari in your file, instead of `\dn` with an input convention)?

Comment: since the space following a command simply indicates the end of the command, it is dropped after that function has been performed.  if you want a real space, you need to indicate it more clearly.  several ways: `\S\ \R`, `{\S} \R`, `\S{} \R`.

Comment: The fact that `\S\R` and `\S \R` are equivalent is very fundamental to TeX — when TeX encounters the backslash and then the S, it skips ahead past any spaces, and then encounters `\R`, exactly the same as if you'd typed `\S\R`. So you need to find an alternative solution. (BTW, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408336/48) for the direct Unicode way instead of `\dn`.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, thanks for pointing out the XeTeX + UTF-8 Devanagari approach - will give it a try.